# Error while executing NS2 nam : libstdc++.so.6

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ns2

Firstly I am new to Ubuntu.

I have installed NS2 in my ubuntu14.04.

installtion was fine. and when i tried ns in terminal it shows %.
But when I tried nam, it is showing some errors regarding the libraries.

Finally I got:  error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file.

I have the latest version of g++.

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

? May be you installed a 32bits (i686) 'nam' package, and your OS is 64bits (x86_64) ?
Or vice versa.

This command will reply with i686/x86_64 : `$ uname -m`

? How did you install 'nam' ?

-

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)

Comment: I have installed ns2 using the steps in the following blog. http://installwithme.blogspot.in/2014/05/how-to-install-ns-2.35-in-ubuntu-13.10-or-14.04.html

Comment: I have added the library path for libstdc++ in the .bashrc . And now I am getting the following error : nam: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Comment: on running $ uname -m i got x86_64